# Integração entre PHP e R

Tags: php, r, matemática

Estou elaborando um projeto com php e resolvi usar R para cálculos estatísticos.

Porém estou com dúvidas quanto a maneiras de realizar essa integração. Se existe um "padrão de projeto" para situações como essa.

Comment: Parece que em inglês você encontra bastante coisa. Não vou tentar traduzir nada porque nunca usei php. Mas aqui tem um exemplo bem básico: http://www.r-bloggers.com/integrating-php-and-r/

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o pacote [php-r](https://github.com/kachkaev/php-r) para fazer a integração entre os serviços.